# ajax function not triggering on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to use this: https://github.com/derekmartinez18/Simple-Ajax-Spotify-Now-Playing and i have this very simple function that shows what i've listened to on spotify:

```
function get_spotify() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'spotify.php',
    data: { request: 'true' },
    success: function(reply) {
        $('.now-playing').html("<p>" + reply + "</p>");
    }
});
};
```

the problem is it's not triggering. but if i'm in the console and i type

```
get_spotify()
```

it does work and the result shows on the page.

this piece of js is called in a .js file before the closing of the body tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "js/build/production.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else
    window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

I tried adding this right after the function in the js file but nothing happens, i tried also a closure function or wrapped in a document ready function, but it just won't trigger. I can't get what the problem is :/ could you help?

Comment: What shows up on your console? Is this code before or after your html with the jQuery file?

Comment: dare I say plnkr.co or jsfiddle.net would be nice.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel nothing.. but as i type get_spotify i get this: http://prntscr.com/6nscpb

Comment: Where is the script located? When do you call the function?

Comment: how you include script in html? jquery should be included before your sctipt

Comment: @epascarello i updated my question. maybe deferring the javascript breaks it?

Comment: From the code you posted we can just say that it works (I even tested it in a fiddle). You'll need to provide more code..

Comment: @vlrprbttst We shouldn't have to go to an external site to figure out the problem. I did inspect it though, and I find no reference to jQuery on that site.

Comment: @vlrprbttst, are you try simple call `get_spotify()` in your script?

Comment: @Mackan all scripts minified and join to `production.min.js`

Comment: @Grundy and the first thing I see when I load the page "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" from production.min.js, line 4

Comment: @Mackan that must must some other plugin, no worries everything works and yes jquery is minified inside production.min. you can find everything on www.valeriopierbattista.com - this is weird

Comment: @Mackan, yep, but i guess OP simple not call `get_spotify` in his code

Comment: @vlrprbttst at least you should turn off minification

Comment: This is getting too chatty, but to be honest: If you have a warning on "object is not a function", everything is not fine - atleast we can't assume so. Something is causing your code to fail, you're asking people to help and there is an unknown error from a minified library - http://jsfiddle.net/3f1912bm/1/

Comment: @vlrprbttst for checking add log before calling `get_spotify` inside `get_spotify` and inside success callback, so you can say in what place fail

Comment: @vlrprbttst possibly ajax fail after error in js

Comment: @vlrprbttst here `$(window).resize(function() {
navHeight();
})();` here you try call function from object, so remove last parentheses

Comment: @Grundy He did this so that a resize event can be triggered at page load. So this might be what he wants: `$(window).resize(function() { navHeight(); }).resize();`

Comment: @blex or this is simple typo :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your code in a fiddle, and it works by it self. But when I add some code from your [unminified](http://valeriopierbattista.com/js/build/production.js) js file, it halts all execution.

So, while I can't point to every possible error in that huge production.min.js file, I know there are errors and they are stopping the code from progressing.

This is a few lines, that was easy to find, that syntax error (might be encoding issue, but there are errors reported regardless):

```
// JQuery Twitter Feed. Coded by...
$(document).ready(function () {
Â 
Â Â Â Â var displaylimit = 3;
Â Â Â Â var twitterprofile = "vlrprbttst";
Â Â Â Â var screenname = "v
...
```

I'm sure there are others. That file doesn't look very stable

edit:

Apparently the error was due to..

```
$(window).resize(function() { navHeight(); })();
```

Should be:

```
$(window).resize(function() { navHeight(); });
```

Full credits to @Grundy for finding and correcting the error.

Comment: that's how it appears on my editor: http://prntscr.com/6ntgyl but i can't see any syntax error. but the syntax highlighting is not working because there must be some error

Comment: Then that's probably an encoding issue. Regardless there is an error, since the minified script reports "object is not a function". @Grundy seems to be on to something in the "chat" ;)

Comment: On another note: I don't know why you'd merge all scripts like this. It makes it a nightmare to maintain (and debug, as we can see)

Comment: works now, thanks a lot! that error was due to

$(window).resize(function() {
navHeight();
})();

what's wrong with this? thanks a lot!

Comment: Credits to @Grundy for finding it. Glad we could help.

Comment: @vlrprbttst `$(window).resize(function() { navHeight(); })` add event handler for resize event and return jQuery object, so you can't use it as function :-)

Comment: thanks a lot guys! :) @Grundy i know it's off-topic but, how should i write that? it actually works this way, even if it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

The element with class name "now-playing" probably doesn't exist immediately after you declare your function. Try wrapping your call to the function in `$(document).ready(function() { })`:

```
$(document).ready(get_spotify);
```

This passes `get_spotify` as a callback to be called once your page loads.

Comment: @KJPrice don't forget the `()`

Comment: Actually, you want to just pass the function it self. Adding the parens will call the function immediately which is not what we want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your function in global scope and you can call it in when you have your document ready:

```
$(function(){ // this makes sure DOM is ready
    get_spotify();
});
```

Comment: @vlrprbttst, It wouldn't work here as "spotify.php" does not exist on their server. Or at least it would be a strange coincidence if it did.

Comment: @KJPrice that's on my server, not theirs. i'm updating the question with some more info

Comment: @Jai nope, just what i posted

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try by adding below code

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    get_spotify();
    // the rest of the code goes here
});
```

Comment: Oops, mobile just sucks 